# ASP.NET Misconfiguration Improper Model Validation (CWE ID 1174)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datamodel, veracode

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC application.

I have a model with data annotations like this:

```
public class SearchModel  
{
    [MaxLength(11)]
    public string? SSN { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

And I have a controller method that receives an object of this type as parameter:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([Bind(include: "SSN")] SearchModel searchModel)
{
    // do something
}
```

I get a Veracode error

> ASP.NET misconfiguration : improper model validation (CWE ID 1174)

on the definition of the method...

Testing.. If I replace `SearchModel` with `String`, it works. So the problem is the model definition, but I added the data annotations to the property.

What else can I check?

Thanks

Comment: How can it be `[Required]` - but also a nullable string at the same time !?!? If it's required - it cannot be nullable ....

Comment: Yes, you are right I put Required just to test if it works, but still does not work with that Notation.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this flaw (CWE ID 1174) in a controller, then:

1. Avoid `async` method.
2. Use a `Bind` attribute.
3. Use `ModelState.IsValid`

If you are getting this flaw (CWE ID 1174) in a model, then:

1. Use Data Annotation attributes like `[Required]`, `[MaxLength]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I found [here](https://community.veracode.com/s/question/0D53n00007Y92VMCAZ/any-advice-on-clearing-flaw-aspnet-misconfiguration-improper-model-validation) the only way to avoid this flaw is to remove signature `Async Task<>` from the Method..